# xpath conditional select, 'tr' having numbers of 'td' > 2

Tags: xpath

While this seems correct [xpath](/questions/tagged/xpath) (?), it doesn't match in firefox49/firebug nor chrome dev tools 53.0.2785.116

```
//table[@id="foobar"]/tbody/tr[count("td") > 2]
```

I try to select all `tr` having a `count()` of `td` > 2

Comment: Ah, thanks, I'm contaminated by using `document.querySelector('td')` every day :D It's sometimes confusing when using both CSS and Xpath selectors.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`count()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/XPath/Functions/count) function expects a *node-set* as an argument. Don't put the `td` into quotes:

```
//table[@id="foobar"]/tbody/tr[count(td) > 2]
```

Comment: Interestingly count() applied to something that isn't a node-set is one of the few dynamic errors defined in XPath 1.0. But XPath 1.0 is very unspecific about how dynamic errors should be handled.

Comment: But it fails _silently_, no DOM error or such. Just console saying: _no matching nodes_